# Ruby Rails Time zone rush hour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

The last developer is using time in our app like this.

```
:timestamp_requested => Time.now.utc
```

I want to check if `:timestamp_requested` is between `4:15PM` and `6:00PM` CST.

I saw another post that uses `in_time_zone` but not sure how to check for between two times?

```
t = foo.start_time
#⇒ 2000-01-01 14:20:00 UTC
t.zone
#⇒ "UTC"
t.in_time_zone("America/Chicago")
#⇒ Sat, 01 Jan 2000 09:20:00 EST -05:00
```

Comment: use `in_time_zone("Central Time (US & Canada)")` for CST/CDT?

Comment: see list of all time zones with `rake time:zones:all`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to check the time is in the specific range would be to compare hours and minutes:

```
cst = time.in_time_zone("America/Guatemala") # CST whole year
(16..18).cover?(cst.hour) && cst.min >= 15
```

Comment: Love this code. Thank you! Works like a charm and is precise.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try the `use_zone` method

```
Time.use_zone("America/Chicago") { (16..18).cover?(time.hour) && time.min >= 15 }
```

Comment: How does it answer the original question?

Comment: Your logic can be passed into it, just an alternative